# Writing to a file java error

Tags: java, file-io

I am getting a NullPointerException when I am trying to write info to a file. Can anyone help me see what is going wrong?

```
    else if(response == 4){
            System.out.println("Enter the name of the file to save items to: ");
            saveFile = input.nextLine();

            try {outfile = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(saveFile+".txt"));}
            catch (IOException err) {
                outfile = null;
                System.out.println("Error writing to file\n");

            }
            for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {

                outfile.print(items[i].getType() + "\n" + items[i].getName() + "\n" + items[i].getDescription() + "\n" + items[i].getCalories() + "\n" + items[i].getItemSpecifics());
            }
```

Comment: What is the line `outfile = null;` doing?

Comment: You need to check `outfile` before `outfile.print`

Comment: It seems to me you want to put the `for` loop inside the `try` block. That way it will not be executed if the exception is raised on initializing `outfile`.

Answer (score 2):

You're setting your `PrintWriter` object (`outfile`) to `null`, and trying to execute the `print` method on it after that.

That's why you're getting the `NullPointerException`.

Checking the documentation, you can find out that who throws `IOException` is actually the `FileWriter` constructor.

```
Throws:
IOException - if the named file exists but is a directory rather than a regular file, does not exist but cannot be created, or cannot be opened for any other reason
```

So, this is probably your problem. If not, you can simply try to create it like this, you don't need the `FileWriter` part:

```
outfile = new PrintWriter(saveFile+".txt");
```

I've tested both ways in my computer and it works.

Also, remember to call the `close()` method when you finished writing in the file, or else, it won't be modified.

Comment: thats only if there is error, doesnt fix the exception

Comment: @user2989591 Edited. Check why the exception is thrown. That must be your problem.

Answer (score 0):

There could be several places you're getting a `NullPointerException` in the code you pasted:

1. You call `outfile = null`, when catching an exception, then attempt to use it afterwards when it will be null.
2. `input` may be null when you're calling `input.nextLine()`
3. `items` may be null when you call `items.length`
4. `items[i]` may be null when you call `items[i].getType()`

It's difficult to tell without a complete stack trace - debugging into it would be your best bet. The exception may also be occurring inside one of the other functions being called here (`getCalories()`, etc)